# Script and image path errors broken on Default.aspx page

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

Simple aspx page, called Default.aspx. Images are broken and script files are not being found. I know these paths are correct because I can copy them to another aspx page that's not called Default.aspx and they work. I'm at a total loss, only thing I can think of is this has something to do with iis-express? We recently moved from IIS 5.1, and this was working there. Changing the script to /js/test.js seems to work but I don't understand why this is necessary. It doesn't help with the images.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <img src="images/test.gif"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following directory structure:

```
<root>
-js\
-images\
-default.aspx
```

try appending both paths with / to use absolute paths:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="/js/test.js"></script>

<img src="/images/test.gif"/>
```

Comment: thanks Dimitri, from my original post I had tried those paths though. It does not help with the broken images, but strangely does work for the js.

Comment: can you confirm that the directory structure above is true in your case and both, js and images folders are in the root of the website?

Comment: yep, that's correct. The weirdest thing, the paths work from every other page not called Default.aspx.

Comment: Are you using any kind of URL rewriting?

Comment: I am honestly not sure. I'm trying to read up on URL rewriting now, haven't worked with it before.